# How can i access an object in a list with it's property as search query?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a `UserModel` class which converts a JSON body. I now want to search a List of these UserModels with an `emailadres` which I got from a different dart page/file.

I have an `ApiService` class which retrieves all users, it then calls the `UserModel` class to parse and put them in a List. I now want to be able to search the list of `UserModel` with `emailadres` to display the data of this user.

**ApiService class**

```dart
class ApiService {
  Future<List<UserModel>?> getUnacceptedProfiles() async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse(apis.baseUrl + apis.unAcceptedProfiles);
      var response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<UserModel> model = List<UserModel>.from( json.decode(response.body)['data'].map( (x) => UserModel.fromJson(x)));        return _model;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**UserModel class**

```dart
// To parse required this JSON data, do
//
//     final UserModel = userModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

UserModel userModelFromJson(String str) => UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    required this.status,
    required this.result,
  });

  int status;
  List<Result> result;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
    status: json["status"],
    result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    required this.docentId,
    required this.naam,
    required this.achternaam,
    required this.emailadres,
    required this.geboortedatum,
    required this.geboorteplaats,
    this.maxRijafstand,
    this.heeftRijbewijs,
    this.heeftAuto,
    required this.straat,
    required this.huisnummer,
    required this.geslacht,
    required this.nationaliteit,
    required this.woonplaats,
    required this.postcode,
    required this.land,
    required this.wachtwoord,
    required this.isAccepted,
    this.isFlexwerker,
  });

  int docentId;
  String naam;
  String achternaam;
  String emailadres;
  DateTime geboortedatum;
  String geboorteplaats;
  dynamic maxRijafstand;
  dynamic heeftRijbewijs;
  dynamic heeftAuto;
  String straat;
  int huisnummer;
  String geslacht;
  String nationaliteit;
  String woonplaats;
  String postcode;
  String land;
  String wachtwoord;
  int isAccepted;
  dynamic isFlexwerker;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
    docentId: json["docentID"],
    naam: json["naam"],
    achternaam: json["achternaam"],
    emailadres: json["emailadres"],
    geboortedatum: DateTime.parse(json["geboortedatum"]),
    geboorteplaats: json["geboorteplaats"],
    maxRijafstand: json["maxRijafstand"],
    heeftRijbewijs: json["heeftRijbewijs"],
    heeftAuto: json["heeftAuto"],
    straat: json["straat"],
    huisnummer: json["huisnummer"],
    geslacht: json["geslacht"],
    nationaliteit: json["nationaliteit"],
    woonplaats: json["woonplaats"],
    postcode: json["postcode"],
    land: json["land"],
    wachtwoord: json["wachtwoord"],
    isAccepted: json["isAccepted"],
    isFlexwerker: json["isFlexwerker"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "docentID": docentId,
    "naam": naam,
    "achternaam": achternaam,
    "emailadres": emailadres,
    "geboortedatum": geboortedatum.toIso8601String(),
    "geboorteplaats": geboorteplaats,
    "maxRijafstand": maxRijafstand,
    "heeftRijbewijs": heeftRijbewijs,
    "heeftAuto": heeftAuto,
    "straat": straat,
    "huisnummer": huisnummer,
    "geslacht": geslacht,
    "nationaliteit": nationaliteit,
    "woonplaats": woonplaats,
    "postcode": postcode,
    "land": land,
    "wachtwoord": wachtwoord,
    "isAccepted": isAccepted,
    "isFlexwerker": isFlexwerker,
  };
}
```

**Data fetch part in userView**

```dart
  _singleProfilePageState({required this.emailadres});
  late List<UserModel>? _userModel = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getData();
  }

  void _getData() async {
    _userModel = (await ApiService().getUnacceptedProfiles())!;
    Map<UserModel, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(_userModel);

  }
```

**profileview page**

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:skoolworkshop/colors.dart';
import 'package:skoolworkshop/main.dart';
import 'package:skoolworkshop/profiles.dart';
import '/Model/userModel.dart';
import 'package:skoolworkshop/apis.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'api_service.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


import 'Widgets/profile_widget.dart';

class singleProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  singleProfilePage({Key? key, required this.emailadres}) : super(key: key);
  String emailadres;

  @override
  State<singleProfilePage> createState() => _singleProfilePageState(emailadres: this.emailadres);
}

class _singleProfilePageState extends State<singleProfilePage> {
  final String getAcceptedUser = apis.baseUrl + apis.acceptedProfiles;
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");
  DateFormat properDate = DateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");
  String emailadres;

  _singleProfilePageState({required this.emailadres});
  List<UserModel>? userModel = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  void getData() async {
    userModel = (await ApiService().getUnacceptedProfiles())!;
    final filteredUsers = userModel?.where((um) => um.result.indexWhere((r) => r.emailadres == emailadres,) >= 0,);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
        'Profiel',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
      )),
      body: ListView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        children: [
          ProfilePictureWidget(
            imagePath:
                // "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/113499/screenshots/12787572/media/3a8bf7d51271e03e8beaef830c5babf2.png?compress=1&resize=1600x1200&vertical=top"
                "https://www.personality-insights.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/default-profile-pic-e1513291410505.jpg",
            onClicked: () async {},
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 12),
          //Naam en email worden meegegeven in buildName methode :)
          buildName(),
          const SizedBox(height: 6),
          const Divider(
            height: 20,
            thickness: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          buildInfo(),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          const Divider(
            height: 20,
            thickness: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildName(/*results*/) => Column(
        children: [
          Text(filteredUsers[0].Results[0].naam + "Achternaam",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
          ),
          Text("Emailadres", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1)
        ],
      );

  Widget buildInfo(/*results*/) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Docent informatie",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        "Geslacht: "
                        "Vrouw "
                        "Geboortedatum: "
                        "01-01-2000",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1)),
                Expanded(
                    child: Text("Rijbewijs: " "Ja         " "Auto: " "Nee",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1))
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Text("Telefoonnummer: " "06-12345678",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1)),
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        "Adres: "
                        "straat:   "
                        "nr:  "
                        "postcode:  "
                        "woonplaats: ",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1))
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: As a side note, your use of `late` on `_userModel` is redundant as you are assigning it a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` to filter the user list based on your criteria and `indexWhere` to search the inner results.:

```dart
final filteredUsers = model.where(
  (um) => um.results.indexWhere(
    (r) => r.emailadres == 'your email address',
  ) >= 0,
);
```

Comment: Then how can i be able to get specific data from ```filteredUsers``` in my ```Widget build```? Like: naam, achternaam, geboorteplaats?

Comment: @AnnevandenBosch Each `UserModel` has `results`, and each `Result` has what you're looking for. The "best" way to access the properties depends on how your UI is laid out, but the simplest way would be something like `filteredUsers[0].results[0].naam`. But if the way to marry your model to your UI isn't plainly obvious, that's a good sign that you need to refactor one of them.

Comment: yea, i can't acces ```filteredUsers``` out of the ```_getData``` class, do i need some keywords or something to show the data in my build? For better overview, here is my entire ```profileview``` file

Comment: @AnnevandenBosch See [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).